# Why on earth is jack showing up in the sequence of alert boxes?

Tags: javascript

```
Object.prototype.jack = {};

var a = [1,2,3];

for(var number in a){
    alert(number);
}
```

Could anyone tell me why the word "jack" jumped out of the alert box?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), but you should be using a regular `for` loop...

Comment: Because `jack` is an enumerable property and you are iterating over all properties of `a`. Related: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/218196)

Answer (score 5):

Simple - arrays are objects in javascript so by adding:

```
Object.prototype.jack={};
```

You've added an enumerable property 'jack' to all objects (and by that to all arrays).

once creating your array "a" and looping through all of its properties

```
for(var number in a)
```

You are sure to get a 'jack' alert. To avoid it showing up you can use `.hasOwnProperty()` to make sure all alerted properties are not inherited. or use a regular

```
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++)
```

loop.

Answer (score 3):

The [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop iterates over properties.  It's only recommended (by Mozilla and other authorities) to be used on Objects, but not Arrays.  If you insist, this is the correct way to iterate over an object and it will work for an array (most of the time).

```
for (var number in a) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, number)) {
        alert(a[number]); // shows 1 then 2 then 3
    }
}
```

To do it the generally accepted way,

```
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    alert(a[i]);  // same as above
}
```

My personal preference is:

```
for (var val, i=0; val = a[i]; i++) {
    alert(val);  // same as above
}
```

Comment: But why in this situation jack comes out?

Comment: Properties on a prototype are not an owned property.  So if we ask `a.hasOwnProperty('jack')` it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not checking if `jack` is a property inherited from `prototype` or not. Try this instead:

```
Object.prototype.jack={};

var a = [1,2,3];

for (var number in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(number)) {
        alert(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: But why in this situation jack comes out?